# Convert a int_list() with configurations to bool_list()

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I try this to get my goal output:

```
pin_configuration = [[1, 1, 3], [2, 2], [3, 3, 1], [4, 4]]
bool_list = [[False] * 68 for r in range(68)]

    for r, j in pin_configuration:
        bool_list[r - 1][j - 1] = True
```

Now I have a error:

```
for r, j in pin_configuration:
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

I want this:

```
bool_list = [[True, False, True,False,...], [False, True, False, 
False,...], [True, False, True, False,...]]
```

Comment: can you provide an example for desired output?

Comment: How is the `bool_list` related to the `pin_configuration` list?

Comment: @HarshithThota the bool_list is my output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you code and data correctly, each item in `pin_configuration` begins with the target index, and then the indices to set to True.

In python3, using [extended iterable unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/), you can do the following:

```
for r, *indices in pin_configuration:
    for j in indices:
        bool_list[r - 1][j - 1] = True
```

to adapt it to python2 you have to change it like this:

```
for item in pin_configuration:
    r = item[0]
    indices = item[1:]
    for j in indices:
        bool_list[r - 1][j - 1] = True
```